# How to make three routers see each each devices connected across them?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, asuswrt

I have 3 routers. 1 of which is from my ISP and the other 2 I use to extend my wifi connection on ground floor and second floor of our house. See setup in image below.

[image]

[I was following this tutorial.](https://youtu.be/LFdGsLofmds) But it seems that for my use case that two routers are connected to one modem, It doesn't seem to apply.

My Problem is that Router 2 and 3 cannot see devices connected to either one of them. Hence, if my NAS is configured on router 2, only devices connected to Router 2 could see it and not those on router 3 which would make it impossible for me to configure my IP Cameras connected on router 3 to record on the NAS.

To make matters worst for me, I can't make Router 2 work in AP mode since alot of its features are disabled like traffic analysis etc hence I had it work in router mode unlike Router 3. See differences in features below.

Router 2 in AP Mode.

[image]

Router 2 in Router Mode.

[image]

I tried changing the LAN IP address of my router 2 to the same octet used by my router 1 and 3, but to no avail, internet and lan is not working at all. Internet would only work if I changed the WAN IP address to the same octet of the router 1, but if I had it that way, the router wont allow me to change the LAN IP address to the same 3rd octet as it says LAN and WAN Ips should be different.

Other notes:

- DHCP is enabled on Router 2 and 1
- DHCP is disabled on Router 3
- I cannot disabled DHCP on Router 1 along with manually assigning IP
- address to certain macs, as this is an ISP modem and I have no admin
  access.

How can I configure this network to make router 2 and router 3 see devices connected on each other so that they can share NAS as well as be able to configure the routers 3 gateways no matter where I connect to?.

BTW, my Aim is:

- I am trying to save around 10-15 bucks and wiring mess by not buying another 20 meter CAT6 ethernet cable and making Router 2 the main router and connecting my Router 3 to router 2 instead of router 1. I am also trying to make router 1 still useful and accessible to the network since router 1 has free 3x gigabit ports that my router 3 wifi repeater doesnt have. Hence if I connect our smart tv and another old IP Camera via LAN, other devices should still be able to see it in the network to be able to take advantage of being able to configure the gateways of routers etc.

I just happen to read somewhere too, that apparently, the setup that I have atm where my router 2 cant see the other devices on router 3 is what is called a [Cascaded network as seen in this blog.](https://robotpoweredhome.com/cascaded-router-network-address-must-be-a-wan-side-subnet/)

Comment: What do you mean by "see"? Do you only need to reach the cameras by their exact IP address, or do you also need the cameras to automatically show up in some kind "device discovery" list? Depending on requirements, there could be two very different answers.

Comment: Turn off DHCP on routers 2 and 3, might also have to configure bridging (not sure, been a while) and let router 1 handle the whole network. It sounds like you'd be better off with either a mesh wifi system or just wireless access points than multiple routers

Comment: @Mokubai Routers 2 & 3 sort of acts like a mesh network already as they both have the same SSID and passwords. My problem really is that interconnectivity of devices between two networks are not yet possible with what I have done atm. I am having trouble forcing router 2 to work in router mode just to have access to other advance features asus has, instead of making it an AP like my router 3 does. Now I am left with advance router features on the Asus, but non of my devices could see each other on both routers.

Comment: These advanced features aren't all that effective anyway if the router is not the outermost router in your network. Just forget about them.

Comment: @DanielB , yea, but I kind of just want to make it work even with just a few devices connecting to it on the 2nd floor of the house. Anyhow, in light of the answer below, I guess I would really have to set Router 2 as my outermost router then, rendering my ISP modem useless at least in terms of being able to use its gigabit ports as i will no longer be able to use it to network devices for them to see each other on the network for NAS purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried changing the LAN IP address of my router 2 to the same octet used by my router 1 and 3, but to no avail, internet and lan is not working at all. Internet would only work if I changed the WAN IP address to the same octet of the router 1, but if I had it that way, the router wont allow me to change the LAN IP address to the same 3rd octet as it says LAN and WAN Ips should be different.

The message is correct – they are physically two separate networks (precisely **because you have a router in between**!), so their IP network numbers *must* be different. Changing the network numbers to be identical will not help you here – (if a city has two streets that happen to be identically named, they're still two separate streets).

> I can't make Router 2 work in AP mode since alot of its features are disabled like traffic analysis etc hence I had it work in router mode

If you want to merge both sides into a single flat network, Router#2 must not be acting as a router. If Router#2 acts as a router, you will have two subnets on both sides. You can't really have it both ways at the same time.

So if you want "traffic analysis" &c. then you will need to keep two separate subnets and route traffic between them. That's a normal thing to do (plenty of large networks consist of many subnets), and will easily allow you to reach devices across networks *by their exact IP address*, but you won't be able to use 'device discovery' features that some of your camera tools might have.

But at least in my (short) experience with IP cameras, only the initial configuration needs to be done with such tools – so you'll have to connect to the same subnet *at first*, but once you've assigned them an IP address once, you'll be able to reach them across routers just fine.

To make this work, add a static route on Router#1 pointing it towards Router#2's subnet:

```
Destination network:  192.168.2.0 / 24
Netmask:              255.255.255.0
Gateway:              192.168.1.??? (Router#2's "WAN" IP address)
```

Afterwards, make sure the *firewall* rules on Router#2 allow packets from the "WAN" side. (It's not really the "WAN" in your situation.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation. Though I will not be able to do your suggestions due to the fact that my router 1/isp modem doesnt allow me to set this static route. All I have for configuration is change the ssid names and password on router 1. In light if what you said, I guess I would really have to set Router 3 as my main router and connect router 2 on it via LAN while also buying another 20 meter ethernet cable to connect router 2 to router 3. Router 1 will then just serve primarily as an internet provider with wlan disabled and lan ports being used just for internet.